# Some question regarding analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I know that the function $\;f: \Omega \to \mathbb{Z} \; z \mapsto f(z) := {e^z\over z}$ is analytic in the set restricted by the disk $B_\gamma:=\left\{ z \in \Omega\ \big|\ |z-3/2|=1 \right\}$?

That's my logic: as $z=0 \notin B_\gamma$ then we know that $\;f(z)$ is analytic within the set as a product of functions, that are analytic within the set.

Is it true or am I missing something? Is this a general way for deciding if the function is analytic or not on the set(not taking into account CR-equations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that product of analytic functions on some domain $D$ is an analytic function on the same domain. So as  that $\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic in ${\mathbb C}\backslash \{0\}$ and $e^z$ is analytic on the same domain (and of course on whole ${\mathbb C}$), the function $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z}$ is analytic on ${\mathbb C}\backslash \{0\}$ , and also including on the domain you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, this eliminates my question absolutely

Answer (score 1):

Your logic works, because products of analytic functions are indeed analytic. The proof is simple. Since $f, g$ are complex differentiable, it follows that $(fg)^\prime = f^\prime g + fg^\prime$ exists. Hence $fg$ is complex differentiable and thus analytic.

If you want a specific reason, finding the complex derivative of your function (with the above method) is as direct a proof as you can get.